# Creating a pandas dataframe from an unknown number of lists of columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have limited my requirements to 5 columns and 3 rows for easy explanation. My column header will come to string and my rows will come to a string. I want all the rows to be added to a dataframe. Here is what I have tried

```
import pandas as pd

Column_Header = "Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5" # We have upto 500 columns
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=Column_Header.split(","))


#we will get upto 100000 rows from a server response
Row1 = "Val11,Val12,Val13,Val14,Val15"
Row2 = "Val21,Val22,Val23,Val124,Val25"
Row3 = "Val31,Val32,Val33,Val34,Val35"
df_temp = pd.DataFrame(data = Row1.split(",") , columns = Column_Header.split(","))
pd.concat(df,df_temp)
print(pd)
```

Comment: Every time you received a Row, add it by: `df.loc[-1] = Row.split(",")`, then adjust the index: `df.index = df.index + 1`

Answer (score 2):

The best and fastest is create list of all data by `list comprehension` and call `DataFrame` constructor only once:

```
Column_Header = "Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5"
Row1 = "Val11,Val12,Val13,Val14,Val15"
Row2 = "Val21,Val22,Val23,Val124,Val25"
Row3 = "Val31,Val32,Val33,Val34,Val35"

rows = [Row1,Row2,Row3]
L = [x.split(',') for x in rows]

print (L)
[['Val11', 'Val12', 'Val13', 'Val14', 'Val15'], 
 ['Val21', 'Val22', 'Val23', 'Val124', 'Val25'],
 ['Val31', 'Val32', 'Val33', 'Val34', 'Val35']]


df = pd.DataFrame(data = L , columns = Column_Header.split(","))
print (df)
    Col1   Col2   Col3    Col4   Col5
0  Val11  Val12  Val13   Val14  Val15
1  Val21  Val22  Val23  Val124  Val25
2  Val31  Val32  Val33   Val34  Val35
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is a viable option, it would be simpler to leave all the data munging to `pd.read_csv`. Convert all your strings to a single multiline string, and pass it through a `StringIO` buffer to `read_csv`.

```
import io    
data = '\n'.join([Column_Header, Row1, Row2, Row3])
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data))
df

    Col1   Col2   Col3    Col4   Col5
0  Val11  Val12  Val13   Val14  Val15
1  Val21  Val22  Val23  Val124  Val25
2  Val31  Val32  Val33   Val34  Val35
```

---

If you're on python2.x, the `io` module is available as the `cStringIO` module, so you'd have to import it as:

```
import cStringIO as io
```